# force a button to overflow on parent if width parent is less

Tags: html, css

I have a button I am trying to make it so that even though its parent is smaller than the width of the button, I want the button to never modify the width of the button no matter that its parent is smaller than the width of the button. in this case for example the text of the button is scrolling to a single line.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.container button{
   overflow:hidden;
   width: 200px;
   max-width:100%;
   background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <button >I need overflow this button in one line</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

if for example the width of the parent was 10px, I still want it to preserve the size of the button without scrolling to the next line.

How can I do this?

Comment: To prevent the button label from wrapping onto a second line you can specify `white-space: nowrap`. I don't fully understand what you're trying to do with "the button next fits the content of the parent", but perhaps the `nowrap` rule will suffice?

Comment: @motto I want the button to never change its original width (the text is moved to the next line by the width of its parent), even if its container is smaller.
I want the button to never modify the width of the button no matter that its parent is smaller than the width of the button.

Comment: Adding `white-space: nowrap` to your existing rules in `.container button` should achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`white-space: nowrap;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) on `button`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container button {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: green;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <button>I need overflow this button in one line</button>
  </div>
</div>
```